# how to disable waiting "press enter" after executing bash script over cron

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

Cron:

```
1-59 * * * * orangepi /home/orangepi/message.sh > /dev/pts/4;
```

message.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\033[37;1;41m WARNING \033[0m"
```

After executing I need press enter that return to console(root@orangepi:/home/orangepi#).

Comment: Could you try typing a command without pressing enter first? I believe your terminal should still be working, it only looks visually messed up

Comment: Yes, I can enter any command. I knew this:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have opened `/dev/pts/4` for writing, and wrote the output of `echo` into it, nothing more than that. There is no execution/interpretation of the `echo` command by your shell, so your shell does not display a new prompt.

If you want to execute a command from one terminal to another, you can try non-standard tools such as [ttyecho](http://www.humbug.in/2010/utility-to-send-commands-or-data-to-other-terminals-ttypts/):

```
sudo ttyecho -n /dev/pts/4 'echo -e "\033[37;1;41m WARNING \033[0m"'
```